# ImageButton images not resized

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton:

```
<toolkit:ImageButton Style="{StaticResource transportButtonStyle}" Click="SeekBackwardClick"
                                 NormalStateImageSource="/Assets/Images/rewind.png"
                                 HoverStateImageSource="/Assets/Images/rewind.png"
                                 PressedStateImageSource="/Assets/Images/rewind.png">
</toolkit:ImageButton>
```

However, when I change the Width or Height parameters, the images are not scalled proportionally. When it concerns an

```
<Image ...>
```

tag, it works fine because I can set the Stretch attribute but this is missing from the ImageButton. Easiest way to get this functionality on ImageButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the control template to make the Images inside stretch. I think I left them non-stretched so that I could swap image assets without needing to update the sizes of the buttons. I guess I could add some property to the button class bound to the images to enable an easy way to control it. But changing the template should work for you for now.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice to apply the "Stretch" property to the hover/normal/pressed images. Thanks!

Comment: hey filip, sorry to contact you this way... couldn't find your email anywhere. i am done with my app and everything is working great but i discovered a memory bug. my viewmodels are being retained when i change my imagebutton to button the problem goes away. are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your control? here's are the imagebutton parameters that are causing the issue: Command="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.NavigateToTopicPageCommand}"

Comment: sorry, ignore what i said. it's my own issue.

Comment: @FilipSkakun I'm sorry to ask this but how do i edit the template?  Everytime i right click the control and go to Edit Template > Create Empty.  My app crashed after running it.  I'm not sure how I am supposed to edit.  I was able to edit the template for my regular button control but not the ImageButton control.  Thanks.

Comment: I usually hand edit the XAML and I am pretty sure all template parts are required for the control to work. I haven't tested it wothought them, so you would need to do "Edit Copy", then set the Stretch property in them.

Comment: @FilipSkakun  When I try "Edit Copy" I got the same exact template if i try "Create Empty" which is the following: "<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="controls:ImageButton"/>"  It doesn't have anything in it like if I do edit copy of regular button Controls.

Comment: Strange. Well, I updated the control to have a `Stretch` property, so you can grab it from the latest sources and provide that property or derive the template from the [current one](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1e9b95dbae1c#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/ImageButton/ImageButton.xaml).

Comment: @FilipSkakun I just want to say thank you very much for adding that stretch property.  It does exactly what I wanted it to be.